# showing project folder in title bar for Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to show the last folder in the title bar?  If you have multiple instances of VS Code open, it is difficult to distinguish between them from the task bar.  If both instances are open on say a file called 'main.ts', you will see 'main.ts' in the taskbar item.

Currently, the title would be `[filename open] - [folder open]` (e.g `main.ts - angular2-training`. Is it possible to invert them to become `[folder open] - [filename open]` (e.g `angular2-training - main.ts`?

Comment: There is a vscode extension that changes the color of the active tab and/or the title background, and/or add a label to the title bar based on a regex.
This is extremely helpful for monorepos, or big workspaces with many sub-projects Disclaimer - I wrote the extension
Its called [ColorTabs](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=orepor.color-tabs-vscode-ext)

Comment: `"window.title": "${folderName}"` in settings JSON

Answer (score 236):

### Use `window.title` in user/workspace settings

[The documentation is here](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_10#_configurable-window-title) with the full list of options of what can be shown. It's quite flexible.

In your case, to display `angular2-training - main.ts` you can use this

```
{
  "window.title": "${rootName}${separator}${activeEditorShort}"
}
```

---

<sub>**Older VS Code versions**</sub>

<sub>The above only works in **v1.10** and up. Here's how to do it in older versions:</sub>

<sub>[**v1.9, v1.8**](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_8#_new-editor-settings) - `"window.showFullPath": true` shows the full path to the current file, so you can at least see the project folder. Note this config is unsupported after v1.10</sub>

<sub>**v1.7 and below** - it's not possible</sub>

Comment: This is a wrong answer. This just shows the full path to the file, which makes the windows even less distinguishable.

Comment: @Inrego with the v1.10 release, exactly what the OP wants is now possible, and I've updated my answer. Please consider retracting your downvote :-)

Comment: Yes, I've been following the issue on GitHub. I've changed my downvote, as the answer is now substantially better than when I initially voted on it.

Comment: The default does contain the foldername now, but I prefer ONLY the folder name, so I can distinguish several VSCode editors from my toolbar. "window.title": "${folderName}"

Comment: For me, I was confused why certain projects were showing window titles differently. I hadn't known about the User and Workspace tabs. Setting `window.title` in my User tab produced the results I was hoping for. This answer would be clearer if it explained that. +1 anyway. Thanks.

Comment: I changed mine, and immediately wanted to go back and forgot what it was before - don't be like me, but if you are: the default was `${dirty}${activeEditorShort}${separator}${rootName}${separator}${profileName}${separator}${appName}` ;-)

Answer (score 34):

On version 1.13

Go to settings, inside UserSettings add this line to the json blob:

> "window.title": "${activeEditorLong}"

On version 1.41.1

[image]

Comment: This shows the full path for me. I prefer [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41174218/24874) as it just shows the name of the project's parent folder. This answer might show `~/projects/my-project` it where the other approach just shows `my-project`. As these strings can appear truncated in lists/thumbnails/etc I prefer the shorter form. Still gave you an upvote as I can imagine cases where you might need this.

Comment: Perfect! You're spot on!

Answer (score 12):

If you want to be able to identify which project you are working on by looking at the window title bar, one option is to set "window.title" to a custom value in the workspace settings file at

```
/.vscode/settings.json
```

If the file doesn't exist, create it, then add the following to it:

```
{
    "window.title": "<PROJECT NAME> : ${rootName}${separator}${activeEditorShort}"
}
```

This is a simple solution that works rather well.

Comment: I think that setting the preference in the `.vscode` folder would force it on all IDEs that open the project. This behaviour seems like a user preference as I can't imagine it making a difference to any metric that the project should worry about.

Answer (score 12):

based uploaded image:

> 1,2: Go to Setting
>
> 3: Search **windows title** in search box
>
> 4: Type this statement in windows title box:

```
${dirty}${separator}${rootName}${separator}${activeEditorShort}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Tested in 1.44

The setting which matches the OPs problem... not being able to tell which VS Code editor is which *from the taskbar*... is:

```
"window.title": "${folderName} ${separator} ${activeEditorShort}"
```

I prefer the simpler

```
"window.title": "${folderName}"
```

`${activeFolderShort}` and friends, don't do what I want, as these follow the folder the active file is in. Whereas I want the folder of the whole "project" shown at all times.

Also, when browsing from the taskbar, I don't care what file is active - it is just noise. I care about the project (i.e. folder). On many occasions, every open VS Code will "main.rs" as the active file, so it is pointless to show it!

Editing the settings in json format even includes intellisense now, so you can see all the options without even having to look them up, and they appear as soon you save the settings file. No need to reload. Awesome!

Comment: I agree, "window.title": "${folderName}" is more than enough

Answer (score 3):

Just some tweaks i found out:

```json
  // will not work on workspace settings.json -> only global
  "window.titleBarStyle": "custom",
  // show only the name of the workspace folder in the title bar
  "window.title": "${folderName}",
  // remove the useless icons on the top-right
  "window.commandCenter": false,

  // make left & top green :-)
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "activityBar.background": "#1e2127",
    "activityBar.foreground": "#95C085",
    "titleBar.activeBackground": "#165900",
    "titleBar.activeForeground": "#ffffff",
  },
```

Comment: THANK YOU! I've been trying to figure this out ever since they added that annoying search box where the title use to be. `"window.commandCenter": false` is what I was missing. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

v1.31 of vscode added these options to `window.title`:

> There are three new variables that can be used within the `window.title`
>   setting:
>
> `${activeFolderShort}`: The name of the folder the file is contained in.
>
> `${activeFolderMedium}`: The path of the folder the file is contained
>   in, relative to the workspace folder.
>
> `${activeFolderLong}`: The full
>   path of the folder the file is contained in.

Answer (score 2):

In addition of the setting:

```
"window.title": "${rootName}${separator}${activeEditorShort}"
```

You now can configure the separator as well with VSCode 1.45 (April 2020)

> ### [Allow customize the window title separator](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/0446c8adad4a8aa6d5881f870a0af18f1f399731/release-notes/v1_45.md#allow-customize-the-window-title-separator)

A new setting **`window.titleSeparator`** allows to change the separator that is used in the window title.

> By default a dash is used.